# Implementing SMP properly on a Linux/MIPS platform

Tags: linux-kernel, multiprocessing, mips, interrupt, sgi

I have been trying to get SMP support working again on a port of Linux/MIPS kernel to the SGI Octane (IP30) for the last few weeks now.  Uniprocessor support works fine, but I am running into a *lot* of problems working with the second CPU.  I can boot the machine to the `init` process, but that dies with either a SIGSEGV or SIGBUS a majority of the time.  I have most of the support code in place from patches written 5+ years ago, but I suspect I am either not locking things properly or I am re-enabling IRQs unexpectedly.

Some background of the hardware:

The MIPS R10000-series CPU implements 8 interrupts, `IP0` to `IP7`:

- `IP0` and `IP1`: Software interrupts only and are currently not used for much.
- `IP2` to `IP6`: Generally routed to some other hardware function for handling
- `IP7`: The R10K timer/counter/compare interrupt.
- R10K supports the MIPS-IV ISA, and has both an I-cache and D-cache.

  - I-cache is 32kB, VIPT, 2-way, and 64-byte linesize.
  - D-cache is 32kB, VIPT, 2-way, no aliases, and 32-byte linesize.
- R10K L2 cache is 2MB, 2-way, and 128-byte linesize.
- R10K is superscalar, employs speculative execution, and can execute out-of-order.
- Octane is cache-coherent, thus does not suffer from the effects of speculative execution.
- Specifically, I have an R14000 dual module in this system.  Not much is known about it other than it's mainly an R10K with a die shrink and faster clockspeeds.  SGI has never released hardware datasheets on this processor, nor any errata information.

Octane has an ASIC called `HEART` as both its memory controller and interrupt controller.  `HEART` was designed to support up to 4 processors and has 64 interrupts (IRQs) available.  These 64 IRQs are divided into several priority levels and are mapped to the R10K CPU IPx IRQs above:

- Level 0, IRQs `0` to `15` -> CPU `IP2`
- Level 1, IRQs `16` to `31` -> CPU `IP3`
- Level 2, IRQs `31` to `49` -> CPU `IP4`
- Level 3, IRQ `50` -> CPU `IP5`
- Level 4, IRQs `51` to `63` -> CPU `IP6`

There are some notes about these priority levels:

- Level 0 and Level 1 IRQs are primarily assigned to devices in the system (SCSI, ethernet, etc).
- Level 2 has several uses:

  - IRQs `32` to `40` are also available for use by devices in the system (Especially those that need a higher priority).
  - IRQ `41` is hardwired for power button presses.
  - IRQs `42` to `45` are for debugger signals to the 4 possible CPUs.
  - IRQs `46` to `49` are SMP interprocessor interrupts (IPI) for the 4 possible CPUs.
- Level 3, IRQ `50`, is specifically for the counter/compare timer on the `HEART` itself.  It runs at 12.5MHz (80ns, I think).  It has a single count register and compare register.  From a Linux `clockevent` standpoint, I think this is a better resolution timer for use as the system timer (52-bit counter, 24-bit compare).
- Level 4 is for error IRQs:

  - IRQs `51` to `58` are error IRQs for each of the 8 available `Xtalk` widgets on the XIO Bus (a high-speed bus arranged in a star topology, serviced by the `XBOW` ASIC).
  - IRQs `59` to `62` are bus error IRQs for the 4 possible CPUs.
  - IRQ `63` is the exception error IRQ for `HEART` itself.

---

`HEART` presents several registers for working with interrupts.  Each register is 64-bits wide, one bit-per interrupt:

- `HEART_ISR` - Read-only register to get the list of pending interrupts.
- `HEART_SET_ISR` - Write-only register to set a specific interrupt bit.
- `HEART_CLR_ISR` - Write-only register to clear a specific interrupt bit
- `HEAR_IMR(x)` - Read/write register to set or clear the interrupt mask for a specific interrupt on a specific CPU, represented by `x`.

I use the following code for the basic IRQ ack/mask/unmasking operations

```
u64 *imr;                       /* Address of the mask register to work on */
static int heart_irq_owner[64]; /* Which CPU owns which IRQ? (global) */

Ack:    writeq((1UL << irq), HEART_CLR_ISR);

Mask:   imr = HEART_IMR(heart_irq_owner[irq]);
        writeq(readq(imr) & (~(1UL << irq)), imr);

Unmask: imr = HEART_IMR(heart_irq_owner[irq]);
        writeq(readq(imr) | (1UL << irq), imr);
```

These basic operations are implemented using the `struct irq_chip` accessors within the 3.1x-series Linux kernel, and I protect access to the `HEART` registers using `spin_lock_irqsave` and `spin_unlock_irqrestore`.  I am not 100% certain if I should be using those locking functions in these accessors.

---

For processing all interrupts, the standard Linux/MIPS platform dispatch function takes the following actions:

- `IP7` -> Calls `do_IRQ()` to handle the CPU timer IRQ.
- `IP6` -> Calls `ip30_do_error_irq()` to report any `HEART` errors to syslog.
- `IP5` -> Calls `do_IRQ()` to handle the clockevent IRQ assigned to the `HEART` timer.
- `IP4`, `IP3`, and `IP2` -> Calls `ip30_do_heart_irq()` to handle all `HEART` IRQs from 0 to 49.

This is the code currently used for `ip30_do_heart_irq()`:

```
static noinline void ip30_do_heart_irq(void)
{
    int irqnum = 49;
    int cpu = smp_processor_id();
    u64 heart_isr = readq(HEART_ISR);
    u64 heart_imr = readq(HEART_IMR(cpu));
    u64 irqs = (heart_isr & 0x0003ffffffffffffULL &
                heart_imr);

    /* Poll all IRQs in decreasing priority order */
    do {
        if (irqs & (1UL << irqnum))
            do_IRQ(irqnum);
        irqnum--;
    } while (likely(irqnum >= 0));
}
```

---

When it comes to SMP support, unlike other Linux/MIPS platforms, I do not have something akin to a mailbox register in the hardware to store what kind of IPI action should be taken.  The original code uses a global int array (`ip30_ipi_mailbox`), indexed by the CPUID, for specifying what IPI action to pass on to the other processor.

Additionally, even though `HEART` was designed to support up to 4 processors, SGI only ever produced a dual CPU module.  Therefore, IRQs `44`-`45`, `48`-`49`, and `61`-`62` are never actually used for anything.

Given these global variables:

```
#define IPI_CPU(x) (46 + (x))
static DEFINE_SPINLOCK(ip30_ipi_lock);
static u32 ip30_ipi_mailbox[4];
```

This is the code currently used to send an IPI to the other CPUs:

```
static void ip30_send_ipi_single(int cpu, u32 action)
{
    unsigned long flags;

    spin_lock_irqsave(&ip30_ipi_lock, flags);
    ip30_ipi_mailbox[cpu] |= action;
    spin_unlock_irqrestore(&ip30_ipi_lock, flags);
    writeq(1UL << IPI_CPU(cpu)), HEART_SET_ISR);
}
```

To respond to an IPI, each CPU calls `request_irq` in its initialization code and registers an interrupt handler.  This is the code currently used in the handler to service the IPI interrupt:

```
static irqreturn_t ip30_ipi_irq(int irq, void *dev_id)
{
    u32 action;
    int cpu = smp_processor_id();
    unsigned long flags;

    spin_lock_irqsave(&ip30_ipi_lock, flags);
    action = ip30_ipi_mailbox[cpu];
    ip30_ipi_mailbox[cpu] = 0;
    spin_unlock_irqrestore(&ip30_ipi_lock, flags);

    if (action & SMP_RESCHEDULE_YOURSELF)
        scheduler_ipi();

    if (action & SMP_CALL_FUNCTION)
        smp_call_function_interrupt();

    return IRQ_HANDLED;
}
```

---

---

And that's the background info.

My current kernel configuration has everything except the framebuffer and the "Impact" video driver stripped out.  No PCI, no block layer, no networking, no serial, no keyboard/mouse.  I have a ~7 year old initramfs I am loading up that, if everything works, should drop to a bash prompt.  However, because it loads into RAM, it's capable of exposing memory corruption rather quickly, and I either get the aforementioned SIGSEGV or SIGBUS errors as a result.

Using remote GDB or the built-in KGDB is not an option at present because of the IOC3 PCI device.  IOC3 is a multifunction PCI device that claims to be a single function device and behind it lie the hardware bits for the keyboard/mouse, serial ports, real-time clock, and the ethernet.  Code does not exist yet to get around the IOC3 and access the serial ports directly for remote GDB, and KGDB doesn't know how to talk to the standard i8042 keyboard controller on the IOC3, either.

I have a standard PCI serial card added (Moschip-based), but that driver is apparently not endian safe, thus probing for serial ports panics the kernel.

Getting the following questions answered will, I hope, put me on the right path to getting SMP working by allowing me to better identify the faulty code and focus on making it work right:

- Am I using spinlocks correctly?
- Am I using the *correct* spinlock variants?
- Do I need to add synchronization calls anywhere (i.e., `smp_rmb()`, `smp_wmb()`, etc)?
- Could my problem lie outside of this core platform support code (such as in the video driver)?
- Could I be looking at an unknown hardware erratum corrupting memory at random?
- Could any of the above code be implemented better?  (much of it is code from the original port of Linux 2.6.17 to the Octane, just updated to be more inline with how other things in the kernel work)

Any information that can put me on the right path to figuring this out would be appreciated.  My hope is to get SMP into a usable state (efficiency is irrelevant, I just need it to work), so I can start working on breaking things up into patches and see about getting it included in the mainline kernel at some point.  If I can't get SMP to work, I'll just drop its support and focus on getting the uniprocessor code sent upstream instead.

Comment: Please share your results if you got the solution for this problem.

Comment: I have opened this bug-issue https://bugs.gentoo.org/show_bug.cgi?id=568912 any article like the above? anyone on IP30 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug was ultimately worked out to not assigning the IRQ numbers to their correct handler.  I was initially assigning ALL 64 IRQs to use `handle_level_irq`, which is incorrect for SMP interprocessor interrupts (IPIs).  The fix turned out to assign the 8 CPU-specific interrupts, 42-45 and 46-49, to `handle_percpu_irq` instead.

Answer (score 0):

This case is very interesting : especially if there is a way to reproduce it. Unfortunately I don't have it :) . But there are a lot of things that I would like to check if I have to fix the issue :
1- disable all levels of caching (per cpu) in order to discard faulty snooping and cache synchronization mechanism.
2- Bind all the interrupts on a single CPU and boot the board. If the issue occurs, then I would say the code you added to handle the interrupts on SMP is not the guilty.  Please set the affinity of the irqs to one CPU (let's say cpu0). For this test, keep your code as it is ... Just make sure to modify the affinity of the interrupts to one CPU.

Do not hesitate to share the results.
Hope that helps.

Aymen.

Comment: Octane's are quite common on eBay if you don't mind the shipping charges, nor their electrical draw :)

Comment: That said, I've tried disabling the caches once (passing cca=2 on the kernel command line); and in my interrupt setup (`struct irq_chip`, `.irq_startup`), I should be binding all IRQs to CPU0 except the CPU1 IPI IRQ.  The only thing I haven't done yet is create the `.set_affinity` method to direct all threads run on CPU0.  I've been pondering if that might help, but I wasn't fully certain.